# What is "ache-and-pain-a-me back-o-hardness" in "We the Women"?

Tags: poetry, interpretation, grace-nichols

I need an explanation for what Grace Nichols is trying to say in the following stanzas from her poem "[We the Women](http://poemylovely.blogspot.com/2012/03/we-women-by-grace-nichols.html)":

> We the women **who cut
>
>   clear fetch dig sing**
>
> We the women making
>   something from this
>   **ache-and-pain-a-me
>
>   back-o-hardness**

These two phrases in bold are what I have trouble with and need explaining.

Comment: What do you need help with, exactly? What sort of information are you looking for?

Comment: @Ash i need help with an explanation of the poem. what is she saying in each line?

Comment: Regarding an analysis of the poem, it would be best if you [edit] your question to explain what your initial thoughts are, and detail the specific elements you don't understand. It's a powerful poem, but not that complex. You could start by looking at the sentinel word "yet" (why was this used?) and consider why the clause starting with the next three words is left unfinished (no verb or complement).

Comment: Asking for an interpretation of the second of the two lines is fair enough, but what is unclear in the first line? Please tell us *exactly* what needs explanation here, as the words all have an obvious and simple meaning.

Comment: BTW, I don't know why *all elements* of my earlier edit (including format, reference link, and relevant tags) were rejected, but please fix the spelling error you've introduced into the question title. And for Lit.SE users interested in some context, [the full poem can be found here](http://poemylovely.blogspot.com/2012/03/we-women-by-grace-nichols.html).

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: For the record, the full text of this poem is [available here](http://poemylovely.blogspot.com/2012/03/we-women-by-grace-nichols.html).